# How to access file from a different package with java in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, package

I am using eclipse and I need to access a file that is in a different package for resources using java.

I have tried getClass().getResource() and different variations of it with the path from the current package to the source package but it keeps on causing a null pointer error.

```
file1 = new File(getClass().getResourceAsStream("the path").getPath())
```

I have done the above with the as astream and when i remove the get path it says the input stream is not defined.

I want it to the put the file from the resource package in a temporary file variable so i can use it in this class without the null pointed error.

Comment: A resource is not a file.  You cannot use java.io.File to read it.  And there is no reason to;  getResourceAsStream already returns an InputStream.  If it’s in a different package, you need to call getResourceAsStream on a class in that package, for instance `TypeInOtherPackage.class.getResourceAsStream("path")`.

Comment: @VGR there isn't another class in that package just .brd files.

Comment: Then place a leading slash on the string argument, as described in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29):  `getResourceAsStream("/com/example/" + path)`